# $.ajax does not work in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I've tried this several times and does not work in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. Works in Firefox. What I am doing is using $.ajax to insert data into my document. Below is my code:

```
//Example using jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('li a.example').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "news-stories.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('news_story').each(function(){
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var company = $(this).find('story_company').text();
            var author = $(this).find('story_author').text();
            $('<div class="items" id="link_'+author+'"></div>')
                        .html('<a href="'+company+'">'+title+'</a>')
                        .appendTo('#top-main-content');
            /*$(this).find('desc').each(function(){
              var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
              var long = $(this).find('long').text();
              $('<div class="brief"></div>').html(brief).appendTo('#link_'+id);
              $('<div class="long"></div>').html(long).appendTo('#link_'+id);
              });*/
            });
        }
        });
    });

});
```

I am attempting to load this data with a click function into #top-main-content. Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

I am loading an .xml document styled with .xsl into the browser as news-stories.xml, I am declaring this function within myt news-stories-style.xsl. Please help.

Mike

Comment: if "news_story" is a class, you probably need a "." in front of it, like $(xml).find('.news_story')... Is that the case?  P.S. generally same thing with ids, use "#theid".

Comment: Since he's using XML it's pretty likely that it is actually a tag with that name.

Comment: ah yes.  That rules that out, should have noticed that.

Comment: yes I am using xml so it's a tag

Comment: I was reading something about hash marks on the end of the link after I click `li a.example` I noticed that their is a hash mark on the end, does this have something to do with it? if so, how do i get rid of the hash mark?

Comment: Add a return false to the click function, to remove the hash. Also I think I remember some characters like hash break ajax in ie, so that might be cause of your woes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with this - parsing XML from within jQuery. Decided that I didn't need jQuery for the XML stuff.  so I just loaded it into an XMLDocument, and partied on it *that* way, using regular [XMLDOM methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757828%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
function httpGet (location, cb) {
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                var text = xhr.responseText;
                if (typeof cb == "function") { cb(text);}
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET",location,true);
    xhr.send("");
}

function xmlDocFromText (text) {
    var xmldoc;
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmldoc.loadXML(text);
    }
    return xmldoc;
}


$('li a.example').click(function(){
    httpGet("news-stories.xml", function(text) {
        var doc = xmlDocFromText(text);
        // use XMLDOM methods here
        var elts = doc.getElementsByTagName("news_story");
        for (var i=0; i<elts.length; i++) {
            var elt = elts[i];
            var title = elt.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].text;
            var author = elt.getElementsByTagName('story_author')[0].text;
                ...
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Dude, I was working last night and it dawned on me that I did not have my server turned on and was previewing the file via regual methode and not with an http request. I will try the method above but I got the code to work after I turned my server on. oops. lol.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. Im afraid your path to the xml file is not correct. can you please inform what is the server respond code?

moreover I think inside script tag `<![CDATA[` is not necessary (not sure though, someone pls confirm)

---

hi, i just found more info on this. jquery xml has problems and doesn't work always. moreover if the file is in local file system then it doesn't work fine in IE always, but it works fine when the file is in server.

*Solution*:
convert the xml to json and then use it. helpful link: http://fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

Comment: I am using the click function on a list (menu) manipulated by jQuery.

Comment: it's necessary in my .xml file otherwise it will not parse

Comment: yeh, its necessary for xml but not in html i think. . .however, your code is correct so you can assume it will work on other pc. . .just test by placing an alert function inside alert handler to make the function works